# If $0<\mu(X)<\infty$ and $0<p<q< \infty$. Is $(\int_X |f|^p) ^\frac{1}{p}\leq \int_X |f|^q d\mu) ^\frac{1}{q}$ true?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

If $0<\mu(X)<\infty$ and $0<p<q< \infty$ Is $(\int_X |f|^p d\mu) ^\frac{1}{p}\leq \int_X |f|^q d\mu) ^\frac{1}{q}$ true.

I should say that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$

I think it is but cannot seem to prove, and it is not in my notes. Any help would be appreciated. I cannot seem to get started, I apologize.

Comment: It's not true even for constant function if $\mu(X) >1$.

Comment: It is true for $p,q$ with $1/p+1/q=1$.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: And by true I don't really mean true. Like @JohnMa pointed out, there's no hope of it true for $\mu(X)>1$.

Comment: If $\mu(X) > 1$ then you just need **a factor**. 
If $\mu(X) <+\infty$  and $0<p<q< \infty$ then the general formula is 
$$
\left(\int_X |f|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}\leq \left(\int_X|f|^q\right)^{1/q}\mu(X)^{(q-p)/(pq)}.
$$
(see proof in user31415926535's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\frac{p}{q}+\frac{q-p}{q}=1$, apply Holder's inequality.

$$
\left(\int_X |f|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}\leq \left[\left(\int_X |f|^{q}\right)^{p/q}\mu(X)^{(q-p)/q}\right]^{1/p}=\left(\int_X|f|^q\right)^{1/q}\mu(X)^{(q-p)/(pq)}.
$$

Note Holder's inequality only applies if the condition $\mu(X)<\infty$ holds.

The inequality you ask for will hold provided $\mu(X)\leq1$.

Comment: As your proof shows, we don't need $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, at all.  

If $\mu(X) <+\infty$  and $0<p<q< \infty$ then 
$$
\left(\int_X |f|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}\leq \left(\int_X|f|^q\right)^{1/q}\mu(X)^{(q-p)/(pq)}.
$$
The condition $\mu(X) \leq 1 $ is only needed to eliminate the factor $\mu(X)^{(q-p)/(pq)}$.